# Moving wordpress site from localhost to live server using GoDaddy cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hosting

I'm using GoDaddy cPanel hosting to move my site from localhost. It's the first time I've done this and I've hit a dead end. I've followed the instructions from these [instructions](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/). I've used duplicator as a back-up whilst developing but I didn't use it for the FTP process.

I'm pretty sure there's a step in the process I'm missing but I can't spot it. I exported the database on localhost, created a new one in cPanel, imported across the localhost one. All the files are in the file manager portal but I'm not sure they're in the right place. The file trail is /home/cPanellogin/public_html/files - is this correct?

I've updated the wp-config file -

```
define('DB_NAME', 'new cPanel db name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'cPanel db user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'cPanel db password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

The site link is [here](http://www.havoccreative.com/). I've never done this before so I'm pretty sure I'm missing some steps, any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your files are not in the correct folder. Because if they are in the root folder of your host, even if an error occurs, you would receive an error message.

Comment: @Leonardo I think you're right, interestingly when I use this link www.havoccreative.com/havoc then some semblance of a site emerges. Do I need to transfer all of the files out of the sub folder and directly into the public_html folder?

Comment: yes you need to put all your file in public_html folder

Comment: You must download the zip file from https://wordpress.org/download/ and extract all files in .zip to public_html.

Comment: @Leonardo I've already got all of them in the sub folder can't they just be copied across?

Comment: Please @Mike.Whitehead read carefully the instructions in https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress.

Comment: You must maintain the same folder structure as .zip. If not, wordpress will not be installed. Put all files in public_html, but keep the same directory structure.

Comment: @Leonardo I've already got wordpress installed. It's a site fully developed on MAMP localhost and the files have been copied in to a sub folder by mistake (my error). Why would I need to download wordpress again?

Comment: You do not need to download again. Move all files to public_html. I understand that you have a fresh install. When you do, let me know.

Comment: @Leonardo I've moved them and still nothing showing for that domain. So confusing.

Comment: You could use all-in-one-wp-migration plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/] It is a simple export from one server to another. even localhosts to online server.

Comment: @omukiguy Thanks. I've moved the files across now. I can now access the backend dashboard via wp-admin but the actual site still won't show. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Check your general settings page. Check if the url is the right now. If not update and save.

Comment: @omukiguy Yes, all the links are fine but I'm still getting the holding page. Really frustrating. At least with an error page you have somewhere to start.

Comment: Do you have any file on the site root folder other than index.php named home, index, default? Delete that.

Comment: @omukiguy Yes I've got home.html / layout styles.css / 404.shtml and index.php . Should I delete all of them or just the home file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these ( home.html / layout styles.css / 404.shtml ) away in a folder for backup

[image]

Comment: Please clear your cache or use private browsing. I see the page clearly http://www.havoccreative.com/

Comment: I feel such a fool. Cheers, buddy have a great Xmas!

Comment: That happens to all of us. Thankful for stackoverflow. Cheers.